# adb uninstall keeping sharedpreference android 10

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, adb, android-10.0

I am using the following command to uninstall application using adb, but keeping the sharedpreference data. So that after reinstallation of application i get the data back.

```
adb uninstall -k [package.name]
```

This works for me upto android 9.0. For the android 10 devices the sharedpreference data gets deleted.After reinstallation the sharedpreference data are not shown. Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this code to **AndroidMenifest.xml**

file

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
     >
  </application>
```

Comment: This is a bad idea, please don't do this...this will make the application experience worse for your users by preventing them from backing up the data from your application in the event of getting a new phone.

Comment: @RyanMentley: Conversely, IMHO, nobody should be setting `android:allowBackup` to `true` without having discussed the ramifications thoroughly with qualified legal counsel.